# copy 'has_many' objects with one SQL INSERT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following (this has been simplified to make the question at
hand more obvious):

```
user model has_many favorites
favorite model belongs_to user
```

After a new user is created, I want to copy all the favorites from an
existing user to the new user. Right now I have the following code:

```
# bob is the existing user and sam is the new user
bob.favorites.each do | f |
  u = Favorite.new(f.attributes)
  u.user_id = sam.user_id
  u.save!
end
```

This creates an SQL INSERT for every favorite that bob has.

I know SQL could do this in one command with something like:

```
INSERT INTO favorites SELECT url, sam.user_id AS user_id FROM
favorites WHERE user_id = bob.user_id
```

Does ActiveRecord have something in place for me to do this? I would
be nice to keep the code in Ruby rather than SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A gem called [ar-extensions](https://rubygems.org/gems/ar-extensions) [supports](http://www.snowgiraffe.com/tech/418/ar-extensions-activerecordbaseinsert_select/) INSERT SELECT SQL satements.

```
Favorite.insert_select(
  :from => :favorites,
  :conditions => ['favorites.user_id = ?', bob.user_id],
  :select => ['favorites.url, ?', sam.user_id],
  :into => [:url, :user_id]
)
```

I'm not 100% sure this will work exactly how it is but it should be possible if you dig into the [documentation](http://snowgiraffe.com/rdocs/ar-extensions/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000048).

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and do it in SQL. That "insert_select" syntax from "ar-extensions" (aNoble's answer) is much less readable than a simple SQL statement.

Keep the SQL in a User model method, and if "bob" is always the same User, then code that in and add it to an after_create callback so that your controller is clean as well. E.g.:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  after_create :copy_favorites_from_bob
  def copy_favorites_from_bob
    connection.execute "INSERT INTO favorites SELECT url, #{id} AS user_id FROM
favorites WHERE user_id = '{{put bob's user id here}}'"
  end
end
```

If you are using PostgreSQL, you'll need to make sure the new user_id is an integer:

```
connection.execute "INSERT INTO favorites SELECT url, integer '#{id}' AS user_id FROM
favorites WHERE user_id = '{{put bob's user id here}}'"
```